# Gulp не работает gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'); 

gulp.task('sass', function(){ 
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss') 
        .pipe(sass()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) 
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

task sass выполняется, а watch нет - прикрепляю скрин ошибки. Не понимаю в чем дело. Версия Gulp 4.0.0[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Gulp 4 зависимые таски **должны быть** функцией.

Можно сделать с помощью gulp.series:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
   sass = require('gulp-sass'); 

   gulp.task('sass', function() { 
      return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss') 
    .pipe(sass()) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) 
   });

   gulp.task('watch', function() {
       gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
   });
```

Comment: спасибо. получилось. может кому-то еще пригодится инфо - https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/how-do-i-update-to-gulp-4/